# Simple way to see how many lines NSString drawInRect will use?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, nsstring, drawrect

Been poking around but haven't been able to find an answer here:

Is there a simple way to calculate/view how many lines of text will result from using NSString's `drawInRect` method (in a subclassed UIView's `drawRect` method).

e.g. in the following snippet:

```
    [self.text drawInRect:titleRect withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.] lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
```

How would I calculate how many lines of text are going to result here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `NSString sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` method to determine the size. The CGSize you pass in should have the desired width and a really high value for the height.

Comment: I agree with this answer. I would first calculate how space one line takes up (use on word for example) and then you have the height for one line of text. Then take the total height for your entire block of text and divide with the one-liner you just calculated and you should have the number of lines.

Comment: Thanks @runmad, your comment completed the answer I was looking for. rmaddy your solution was a start but doesn't provide an integer value of the number of lines. Thanks, both.

Answer (score -4):

I ended up with some custom calculations, as sizeWithFont doesn't work correctly with custom fonts. Some rudementary, but working way:

```
NSString *text = post.content;
int cntLB = [[text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]] count];
int numLines = [text length]/38+cntLB/2;
```

where 38 es some threshold parameter which depends on with of text and cntLB/2 refers to double \r\n characters.

Comment: -1 This is a horrible solution for the problem! Not every character renders with the same width and there are also other factors like the linebreak mode that effect how the text is rendered.

Comment: Your answer may work for a very special case but it is not going to work for most cases. What if the text has no newlines but still needs to be wrapped?

Comment: rmaddy, JustSid, this situation handles both. I know its not elegant at all, but the default sizeWithFont doesn't work with custom fonts as it should (try it with Myriad Pro, for example) and you tell. I don't say it is a generic solution, just some custom approach which can save hours of head banging.